# How to handle -904 Invalid identifier error in oracle store procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

My proc is like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INSERT
    IS
      TotalUpd pls_integer;
      err_code number;
      err_msg varchar(500);

      invalid_excep EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(invalid_excep,-904);  
    BEGIN
      insert into test_proc_tbl(un_id) /* this column doesn't exist */
        select 'asd' from dual;

        TotalUpd := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
        commit;

    EXCEPTION

        WHEN invalid_excep THEN
            INSERT INTO err_log(src,typ_ex,ERROR_DESC,ROW_COUNT,RUN_STATUS,UPDATED_DATE)
            select 'TEST','STORE PROCEDURE',to_char(err_code) || '-' || err_msg,TotalUpd,'ERROR',SYSDATE from dual;   
            COMMIT;

        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            err_code := SQLCODE;
            err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,200);

            INSERT INTO err_log(src,typ_ex,ERROR_DESC,ROW_COUNT,RUN_STATUS,UPDATED_DATE)
            select 'TEST','STORE PROCEDURE',to_char(err_code) || '-' || err_msg,TotalUpd,'ERROR',SYSDATE from dual;  
            COMMIT;   

    END;
```

I am trying to insert Invalid identifier error in my log table, purpose of doing this some of my base table will be recreated twice in a week, other team can miss or modify column name. Here my problem is Exception doesn't catch invalid identifier error, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote your procedure, ORA-00904 is a compile time error, you can not catch that with a runtime exception handler.

Simplest workaround is to use dynamic SQL. Instead of:

```
 insert into test_proc_tbl(un_id) /* this column doesn't exist */
        select 'asd' from dual;
```

Use this:

```
execute immediate ' insert into test_proc_tbl(un_id) select ''asd'' from dual';
```

This will compile regardless of the existence of `un_id` column, and you can catch the error. However, you will lose dependecy tracking between the table and your procedure.